# Mysql and wamp does not works together

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

When Mysql service starts wampmysqld service doesnot works and when wampmysqld service works mysql service stops what should i do. I want use mysql database for php and i m on wamp server.

Mysql log file shows following error(I Googled a lot but nothing

```
 `2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count bufferpool pages
   2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
  2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows    interlocked functions
2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
  2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-01-29 19:32:53 6032 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-01-29 19:32:54 6032 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-01-29 19:32:54 6032 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-01-29 19:32:54 6032 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1625977
2016-01-29 19:32:54 6032 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating   a new UUID: fe08916a-c690-11e5-9c58-902b348a5307.
2016-01-29 19:32:54 6032 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-01-29 19:32:54 6032 [Note] IPv6 is available.
 2016-01-29 19:32:54 6032 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
 2016-01-29 19:32:54 6032 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
 2016-01-29 19:32:55 6032 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
 2016-01-29 19:32:55 6032 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
 Version: '5.6.17'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
    2016-01-29 19:36:19 6032 [Note] wampmysqld: Arrêt normal du serveur'
```

Comment: did you change the port to use as both will try to use port 3306

Comment: Both are fighting to use the same `port` - but only one will win :)

Comment: `I want use mysql database for php and i m on wamp` - the m in wamp stands for mysql. Is there something wrong about the mysql server your wamp installation spins up? I.e. please explain why you want to have both mysql server instances running (there might be a reason, even a good one ;-))

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing, its better to use only one MYSQL Server instance on one PC. Backup databases and the remove one of the MYSQL instances. You only need one to run many databases.

Comment: There is no need of runing wampmysql and msqlserver instances together just start up wamp and mysqlserver should be active it is all you need to work with database.